# how to aggregate prometheus counters during a specific time period

Tags: prometheus, promql

This is what my metrics endpoint looks like:

> app_ui_card_open{host="foo.bar.com",card_id="listing_tickets",username="smiller"} 2
> app_ui_card_open{host="foo.bar.com",card_id="listing_companies",username="smiller"} 1
> app_ui_card_open{host="foo.bar.com",card_id="listing_contacts",username="smiller"} 1

There are other similar lines with other usernames but these are all of them for the "smiller" `username`.

I've just started collecting this data over the past week. I'm trying to understand how i can a single count of all of the `app_ui_card_open` counts per username.

This is the query i came up with:

```
sum(increase(app_ui_card_open{instance="foo.bar.com"}[1y])) by (username)
```

However, the produces a value of only `1` for the "smiller" username. I would expect to see the value of `4`; the sum of all those metrics listed above since `1y` would contain the entire dataset.

Is my query wrong? Is prometheus just doing it's estimating even though the data set is really small?

Answer (score 1):

Using `increase` you will get how much the values increased over a period. In your case they increased just by 1. i.e.: `1 -> 1 -> 2`. Use the `sum_over_time` as [the docs say](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time).

> sum_over_time(range-vector): the sum of all values in the specified interval.

after that you group by `username`

```
sum(
    sum_over_time(app_ui_card_open{instance="foo.bar.com"}[1y])
) ​by (username)
```

check [this demo](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=sum(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20sum_over_time(alertmanager_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket%5B10s%5D)%0A)%20by%20(handler)&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=sum_over_time(alertmanager_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket%5B10s%5D)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h) as an example in case your query does not work.

Comment: i understand the words that describe `sum_over_time` but not the results. This query results in `53376` for "smiller".

Comment: did you try to use less than 1 year at `[1y]`? maybe `[10m]`

Comment: just tried `[10m]` and this is still producing values in the thousands which is not accurate.

Comment: I think you have to first reason over `sum_over_time(app_ui_card_open{instance="foo.bar.com"}[10s])` and see what are the values that you will sum. i think they will not be only `1`, `1`, and `2`. It might be many more. Then wrap it into `sum() by()`. I updated the demo query to show how to reason

Comment: i don't understand `sum_over_time`. I can refresh that query every few seconds and the values increase even though my metrics endpoint returns the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following query:

```
sum by (username) (app_ui_card_open{host="foo.bar.com"})
```

Comment: how would incorporate a time range into this query? as in show me this for only the past `[30m]`

Comment: Do you want to know the sum of the current counter values or do you want to know how much the counters have increased in a given time?

Comment: I want to know the increase. I want to be able to answer "how many cards did user X open in the last 6 hours?"

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the number of cards opened by every user during the last 6 hours:

```
sum(increase(app_ui_card_open[6h])) by (username)
```

The query assumes that the `app_ui_card_open` is a [counter metric](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#countet), otherwise the query will return unexpected results.

Prometheus may return unexpected fractional results for integer-only  `app_ui_card_open` metric because of [extrapolation](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). If you need the exact integer results, then try this query in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. It implements the `increase()` function without extrapolation. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for more details.